# Label dot pack not working Mac for Tkinter module python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a calculator that takes in the row and column number in an excel file and calculates either the sum or difference for the two cells. I am trying to use Tkinter in python to develop the GUI. But I am facing an issue, i.e., the `label.pack()` doesn't display anything on my root window. I'm sharing my code below, please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def main():
    print('Hello World!')
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('500x500')
    root.title('Celly_Cally')

    rowLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Row")
    rowLabel.pack(side = LEFT)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: you havent imported the tk module correctly and you therefor need to use (side = tk.LEFT)

Answer (score 0):

Neither you have defined `LEFT` nor imported it.
Either replace it with `str` `'left'`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def main():
    print('Hello World!')
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('500x500')
    root.title('Celly_Cally')

    rowLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Row")
    rowLabel.pack(side = 'left')
    #OR also use this way(below) if you don't wnat to import one by one
    #rowLabel.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

or import `LEFT`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk,LEFT

def main():
    print('Hello World!')
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('500x500')
    root.title('Celly_Cally')

    rowLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Row")
    rowLabel.pack(side = LEFT)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: or you could also use, from Tkinter import * and then keep using (side = LEFT)

Comment: `import *` is helpful but not recommended. Read [`about it`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad). `tk.LEFT` would be better if you don't want to import let's say 10-20 of them